# Rails 4 Asset Pipeline and IE8 Assets

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have a .css file and .js file that should only load for internet explorer 8 and lower browsers. In pure HTML I would typically have:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

How do I manage this within the rails asset pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

As an example for your javascript

    `<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "ie" %>
    <![endif]-->`

And you just name your js file under `assets/javascripts/ie.js`

Look at `stylesheet_link_tag` for your css files.

Check out the docs on the asset pipeline for more info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html